# Executing shell script from a webpage

Tags: php, html, shell

I have a HTML page from which I want to call a shell script. I have placed the HTML page in document root and the shell script in cgi-bin directory. Now, when call the script, instead of getting executing it is getting printed on the page. Can someone help me out here.

HTML Tag:
`<form action = "cgi-bin/test.ksh"><input type = "submit" value = "Submit"></form>`

test.ksh:

```
#!/bin/ksh
touch /var/tmp/Vipul/abcd.txt
echo Content-type: text/html 
echo 
echo 
cat << EOF 
<HTML> 
<meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="1; url=https://HOSTNAME:PORT/PATH"> 
</HTML> 
EOF
```

Comment: Where do you want to execute it? On the server I assume?

Comment: Are you using Apache? Have you set up an handler? If it is Apache you're using, have a look at the manual: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/cgi.html

Comment: Put this in quotes , `echo "content-type: text/html"` as well as the <html> tags, i.e `echo "<HTML> 
<meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="1; url=https://HOSTNAME:PORT/PATH"> 
</HTML> "`

Comment: Harshit, still getting same.

Comment: Yes GrumpyCrouton, on the server

Comment: I changed ksh to sh and now the page is script is getting downloaded.